# spring-boot basic JSP 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can't load a very simple JSP page with spring-boot, getting 404 Not Found.

**src/main/java/SampleWebJspApplication.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**src/main/java/WebController.java**

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>Hello.</h1>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Getting 404 even though debugger shows that "welcome" is being returned from the Controller RequestMapping.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Mar 07 19:35:15 EST 2015 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add this to my **application.properties** file:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Answer (score 8):

I have already tried many solutions, but couldn't find a working one.

If you are using **Intellij IDEA** and reading this while you are pulling your hair: do not try to run Spring Boot application(with dynamic .jsp views) with the IDE's run ▶︎ button.

```
$ cd {your_project_folder_path}

$ ls //Check if you are in the same place with the pom.xml
```

and then type

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Now your application is served at `localhost:8080`.

Comment: that means that problem is with your build tool, not IDE itself

Comment: @fg78nc Please look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Answer (score 4):

Normally Spring boot doesnot require any configuration besides adding dependency while working with Thymeleaf.

To run JSP in Spring Boot, you have to have some configurations:

Dependencies needed:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If you are connecting with MySQL Database then:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In Application.Properties file:

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Now your Good to go !!! :D

Comment: I was missing the dependency. Thanks for the help.
Also, `javax.servlet` was giving an error. Removing it also worked so I think it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In latest spring versions, the properties to be put in application.properties file look like following:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Note **"mvc"** included in **"spring.view.prefix"**

Also, in newer versions of Spring, there is an annotation `@SpringBootApplication` for `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan`