# spring boot not returning 404 for jsps unless tomcat maven dependency scope is compile?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm getting 404s returned by spring boot when trying to render jsp files. My maven config has spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.4.0.RELEASE as the version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I am running the embedded Tomcat servlet container.

I found this SO post [spring-boot basic JSP 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922248/spring-boot-basic-jsp-404-not-found) and set the required `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` properties in my `application.properties` file.

Still 404s.

I then found this SO post [spring-boot-not-finding-jsp-pages-in-war-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199609/spring-boot-not-finding-jsp-pages-in-war-file) and added the requisite dependencies in my `pom` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Still 404s.

On removing the `<scope>provided</scope>` tag, everything started to work. Thinking this tag may have resulted in a different classpath for spring boot and hence turned on a different feature, I turned on the spring boot configuration report using `--debug` and diffed the output with and without the `scope` tag. There was no difference. Both have the following line in the `Positive matches` section:

> WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver matched
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

Can anyone explain why it works without the `provided` scope?

Comment: What's your packaging option, `jar` or `war`?

Comment: packaging option is `jar`

Comment: jsps require war packaging... This is documented in the reference guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

Comment: switching to `war` makes it work, thanks. that page implies that jsps won't work in a `jar` package inside of Tomcat. so what about dropping the maven `scope` setting makes it suddenly work?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JspTemplateAvailabilityProvider.java

Comment: AFAIK `ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspConfig", classLoader)` returns `false` when jasper dependency is `provided`, Since the jasper won't be in the packaged jar when it's provided

Comment: Cheers, thanks. If you want to make your comments the answer I will happily accept them.