# Spring App won't work with JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am new to Spring Framework. Trying to make a Java based Spring MVC project. Here is my main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

When I run the project I get the error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Why Spring can not display JSP files?

[image]

Comment: Download a working project and work off that. A million things can go wrong when setting up a spring project from scratch

Comment: where can i download it?

Comment: What about their website???!@??? https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: thymeleaf template used in this tutorial , and I want to use jsp. I've seen this guide

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples on the internet. Go find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following to `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Edit :You can refer sample project [here](https://github.com/sidgate/webexample)

Below step is not required, but worth a try.

---

As per another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922248/spring-boot-basic-jsp-404-not-found?rq=1), you need following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: match the folder structure. move hello.jsp to WEB-INF/jsp folder

Comment: I added properties, dependencies and moved my jsp file to WEB-INF/jsp folder, but it's still not working.

Comment: For me the basic project works just fine. Please take a look at https://github.com/sidgate/webexample and you can then compare

Comment: thank you very much. This is a great example, it helped me a lot. How did you create this project, what documentation you referred to? I would like to learn Spring MVC, but can't even create a project.

Comment: And another question: when I run your project using Spring Boot configuration in Intellij IDEA, it starts and after a few seconds displays. But when I downloaded the project via Spring Initializr, it does not turn off. there is no problem when i run your project with tomcat , I just want to understand the difference

Comment: I use STS (spring tool suite) for generating the project, haven't worked with Intellij, so cannot help much. But make sure you include `web` dependency in starter project, otherwise it will just be a standalone app

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you, please,  describe how you create a project in STS? I downloaded STS and created a project, but my problem is not resolved.

Comment: @MansurNashaev you have to create spring starter project. Add `web` as dependency when you create a project. Please accept the answer if it solves your purpose